# This arch install not yet working, /sbin/init trouble

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, init, lvm2

I do an lvm2 arch install, as the installation page on the wiki tells.

I do what the wiki page tells, with the mileage: put Grub as boot manager. Set the lvm2 hook on the mkinitcpio configuration. After it completes restart and happens this:

```
starting version 225
/dev/mapper/arch-root was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
/dev/mapper/arch-root: 1269/65536 files (0.9% non-contiguous), 7631/262144 block
s
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs /]# _
```

*The unclean unmount is because the panic when exiting that shell.*

I googled it, but the results seem old to me when am trying to follow them when doing my case.

Got ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the **usr** and **shutdown** `mkinitcpio` hooks.

Credits to Namarrgon from #archlinux at freenode IRC.